# What's the area of effect for the Scarecrow?

Tags: stardew-valley

So after  having some jerkass crows steal some crops for the first time I immediately put up a Scarecrow, since it'll keep the crows away. However, it has a limited range of 20 tiles, as seen in the description:

[image: Prevents crows from attacking your crops. Has a limited range (about 20 tiles)]

So my first thought was this meant that any tile within 20 tiles of the scarecrow would be immune to crows, but I've been poking around online and I'm getting mixed information on how it actually works. Some folks are saying it's a circle with a diameter of 20 tiles, and others are saying it has a radius of 20 tiles (some folks are saying the area is shaped as a square instead of a circle which makes a difference as well). Knowing exactly how this scarecrow works is important to knowing proper placement of them, so I'm looking for a definite answer on how it works.

Can anyone confirm how the scarecrow works via either SCIENCE! or a statement from the developer?

Comment: According to an item in the [1.03 changelog](http://steamcommunity.com/games/413150/announcements/detail/842541922570612288): "Scarecrow range reduce to 8 tiles radius." I would assume, based on the word "radius" and the grid system of the game, that the area of effect is 8 tiles in any direction, yielding a square of 17 tiles on a side (8 + 8 + 1 tile for the scarecrow itself).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This [image](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/mediawiki/images/f/f9/Scarecrow_Range.png) shows the new 8 tile "radius" of the scarecrow.  It looks like a square with the corners missing.

[image]

Comment: Is this confirmed? I'm a bit confused as to why the tiles definition is so different for a scarecrow and sprinklers. (about 20 tiles for a scarecrow means a gigantic 8x8 square, while 24 tiles for a sprinkler means a small 5x5...?)

Comment: It's on the wiki as the radius after the most recent patch which reduced the radius to 8.  It kind of makes sense that a scarecrow, which only requires line of sight to crows, would have a larger radius than a sprinkler which needs to throw water. I agree the in-game descriptions could be clearer though.

Comment: @CoqPwner The sprinkler says 24 TILES, the scarecrow patch notes say a RADIUS of 8. Those are very very different things.

Comment: @Dallium I agree about the patch notes, I'm referring to the in-game description, which is extremely confusing.

Comment: Is there a citation on this? I first figured "radius" would mean under the taxicab geometry that the game generally operates on. This looks more like a Euclidean circle where any portion of the square that is within 8 units counts as in sight.